# Best practices for multiple Custom Feeds functions

Tags: functions, feed

I created two new WordPress RSS feeds in my theme functions:

`// Custom Feed 1
add_action('init', 'customRSS');
function customRSS(){ 
add_feed('feedname', 'customRSSFunc');
}
function customRSSFunc(){
get_template_part('rss', 'feedname');
}`

// Custom Feed 2
add_action('init', 'customRSS2');
function customRSS2(){ 
add_feed('feedname2', 'customRSS2Func');
}
function customRSS2Func(){
get_template_part('rss', 'feedname2');
}

It's working perfect, however based on the DRY concept I feel that may have a better approach to this code instead of adding the whole function for each new custom feed. Is that true?

The tutorial I followed is [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/) if anyone interested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do to keep my RSS Templates together though depending on your version of PHP this may not work but it's pretty clean. You can add multiple feeds here.

```
/** Register Our RSS Feeds **/
function my_rss_templates() {
    add_feed( 'feedname2', function(){
        get_template_part('rss', 'feedname2'');
    });

    // Rinse and Repeat...
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_rss_templates' );
```

<strike>PHP has a name for the above method, (calling a function like that) but off the top of my head I can't put a name to it.</strike>

[Anonymous Function Call](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) - Only available in PHP 5.3 and up.

Comment: Just curious if this still works because the code mentioned above does not validate for me.  There's two ' at the end of get_template_part('rss', 'feedname2'');   - is that a typo or a deliberate hack ?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the logic into a class that remembers the names and the template parts.

Example, not tested:

```
class Custom_Feeds {

    private $feeds = array ();

    /**
     * @param array $feeds
     */
    public function __construct( Array $feeds ) {

        $this->feeds = $feeds;
    }

    /**
     * @wp-hook wp_loaded
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {

        $names = array_keys( $this->feeds );

        foreach ( $names as $name )
            add_feed( $name, array ( $this, 'load_template' ) );
    }

    /**
     * @wp-hook do_feed_$feedname
     * @return void
     */
    public function load_template() {

        $name = get_query_var( 'feed' );

        get_template_part( 'rss', $this->feeds[ $name ] );
    }
}

$feeds = new Custom_Feeds(
    array (
        'feed1' => 'foo',
        'feed2' => 'bar'
    )
);
add_action( 'wp_loaded', array ( $feeds, 'register' ) );
```

Besides that, I don’t think feeds are theme territory. They are not styled data usually.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short alternative way (untested) to the other great answers:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_feeds' );

function custom_feeds()
{
    foreach( array( 'feedname1', 'feedname2' ) as $name )
    {
        add_feed( $name, 
            function() use ( $name )
            {
                get_template_part( 'rss', $name );  
            }
        );
    }
}
```

According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed), we should use the `init` hook and to remember to *flush the rewrite rules* for `add_feed` to work.